# Iframes not working after enabling SSL Certificate

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using Iframe on my website > https://www.merchantcashadvancecalculator.com
It was working fine before enabling SSL

```
<iframe src="https://www.merchantcashadvancecalculator.com/?lfb_action=preview&form=6" style="border:none;" height="400" width="900"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this problem is solved by applying `<code>` tag

```
<code><iframe src="https://www.merchantcashadvancecalculator.com/?lfb_action=preview&form=6" style="border:none;" height="400" width="900"></iframe></code>
```